# symfony2: customizing bundles overriding directory

Tags: symfony, overriding, bundle, twig

For overriding Bundles template , at the first level Symfony search inside **app/Resources/AcmeSampleBundle** directory if it doesn't exist then it read template from **src/Acme/SampleBundle**.
Is there any way for customizing first level directory?
 for example : **app/Resources/AllBundles/**

Comment: Can you please give an example why you would do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use your custom template locator by change service 'templating.locator'. Let check how [LiipThemeBundle](https://github.com/liip/LiipThemeBundle#theme-cascading-order)  do this.